# Fire bullets at an interval continuously while the fire button is held down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

In C# Unity3D, I'm trying to get my bullets to fire at an interval of `bulletTime`. Single shots work perfectly fine at the moment, but when I hold down the fire button, just 1 bullet is created and shot and then nothing else happens.

```
// Left mouse button HELD down.
else if (fireAgain && Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
{   
    StartCoroutine("LoopNShoot");
    fireAgain = false;
}
else if (timerH < bulletTime)
{
    timerH += Time.deltaTime;

    if(timerH >= bulletTime)
    {
        fireAgain = true;
        timerH = 0;
    }
}   
    

IEnumerator LoopNShoot()
{
    pivot.transform.Rotate(triggerAngle,0,0);
        
        GameObject bullet = ObjectPooler.SharedInstance.GetPooledObject(); 
        if (bullet != null) {
                bullet.transform.position = SSpawn.transform.position;
                bullet.transform.rotation = SSpawn.transform.rotation;
                bullet.SetActive(true);
         }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
            pivot.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, originalRotationValue, Time.deltaTime * rotationResetSpeed); 
    
}
```

Im thinking I need to place all my if statements and timer inside the coroutine? But that doesnt seem to help either...

Please ignore the pivot and rotation, it works fine for some animation, the only thing taht doesnt work is shooting bullets continuosly at a set interval while the fire button is Held down.

Comment: You should reformat your code.

Comment: @marsh-wiggle what should be reformated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove these `else` and just do.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (fireAgain && Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
    {   
        StartCoroutine("LoopNShoot");
        fireAgain = false;
        timerH = 0;
    }

    if (timerH < bulletTime)
    {
        timerH += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timerH >= bulletTime)
        {
            fireAgain = true;
        }
    }   
}
```

You could also re-arange this to make clearer how it works:

```
private void Update()
{
    if(!fireAgain)
    {
        timerH += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timerH >= bulletTime)
        {
            fireAgain = true;
        }         
    }
    else
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
        {   
            StartCoroutine("LoopNShoot");
            fireAgain = false;
            timerH = 0;
        }
    }       
}
```

---

I actually thought you anyway already chose the `Invoke` method I showed you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293411/while-loop-timer-with-a-bool-that-doesnt-work-unity-3d)

Comment: Yeah I am using Invoke now, very cool, but I am banned from asking more questions for 2 days now, so I cant ask why my bullets are disappearing early.
I use OnEnable { > Invoke >DestroyBullet , 5 seconds > gameObject.setActive(false)
so I want to make my bullets reset and disable themselves 5 seconds after they have been shot. It works fine, but then after some time some bullets will disappear before the 5 seconds are over, some will just last 1 second others the full 5, and I have 50 pooled objects and only shooting maybe 10 so its not that my pool is running out either.